# Python look for bin referring from other table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like  to create a new feature that obtain the bin number from another table based on its value.

Ref Table:

```
 bin         value
 0           -6.417449e+00
 1           -1.198942e+00
 2           -9.162902e-01
 3           -9.162870e-01
 4            5.000000e-08
 5            3.499993e-06
```

And another transaction data set:

```
index   value
 1       -7
 2        0
```

What i want:

```
index   value    bin
1       -7       0
2        0       3 (-9.162870e-01 < X < 5.000000e-08)
```

Comment: What about some code of what you're doing?

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: According to your logic for bin 3, bin 0 should represent values between -6.4 and -1.2, not -7. Please can you clarify?

Comment: thx for reply, for anything less than -6.417449e+00 will consider as bin 0 , Yes using pandas